# Hide private + protected methods from code coverage report?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

Can I hide private & protected methods from PhpUnit's code coverage report?

I know some other people are suggesting that one should test them "indirectly" but I *really* don't care if they get called or not and I think it's an utter waste of time for me to set up `@covers` for private utility methods.

Here's my `phpunit.xml` if you need to see that:

```
<phpunit
        backupGlobals="false"
        backupStaticAttributes="false"
        bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
        colors="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        processIsolation="false"
        stopOnFailure="false"
        syntaxCheck="false"
        timeoutForSmallTests="1"
        timeoutForMediumTests="10"
        timeoutForLargeTests="60">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">./src/Internal</directory>
            </exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

[image: code coverage]

Comment: Well, if a public method relies on private methods, why would you exclude them? This has no sense to me, really :)

Comment: @DonCallisto Just not worth the effort IMO. Diminishing returns. Unit tests ensure the output is correct, code coverage makes sure I test all the different scenarios are hit. Do I *really* need to make sure I execute every single line of code in my lib, even if I perhaps over-generalized some of my private utility methods? I don't think so.

Comment: Well, in this case, just turn off code coverage, otherwise it does not make sense to apply it only to public methods imho.

Comment: Btw I'm not a fan or integralist of 100% code coverage but I think that if you turn it on, you should make it evaluate every line of code you have

Comment: @DonCallisto I guess we'll have to disagree there. Code coverage has helped me uncover a number of bugs since I started using it. It's definitely useful but I just don't see the value in unit-testing things like `__debugInfo`.

Comment: We have two discordant point of view: happens :)
BTW of course `__debugInfo` it's not a useful thing to debug: don't make such kind of example that are totally no sense please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, it's not a PHPUnit functionality and you must fork [php-code-coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) project and edit the source code. Probably that's not the answer you are looking for but it seems this is the only option right now.

It is comforting that the changes are pretty simple. You might edit `CodeCoverage::getLinesToBeIgnored` [method](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/master/src/CodeCoverage.php#L736) and add extra condition

```
if (get_class($token) == 'PHP_Token_FUNCTION') {
    $methodVisibility = $token->getVisibility();

    if ($methodVisibility == 'private' || $methodVisibility == 'protected') {
       $endLine = $token->getEndLine();

       for ($i = $token->getLine(); $i <= $endLine; $i++) {
           self::$ignoredLines[$filename][$i] = TRUE;
       }
    }
}
```

[image]
Method `getSomething` is ignored without using `@codeCoverageIgnore` or any other doc blocks.